# Could I do without the commandbutton1 in my userform?

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a vba code for a userform in Excel. This userform allows me to display a listbox which shows all the worksheets available...  Then after selecting the desired worksheet in my listbox  and by clicking in my userform one button called " CommandButton1", it selects me the desired worksheet... However I would like simply by selecting and clicking on my desired worksheet in my listbox,  it selects me the desired worksheet( In this way, i would  no need any more to click on my button " CommandButton1" in my userform to select my desired worksheet)...If someone could help me with that, it would be really wonderful.. Many thanks in advance.Xavi please find my code below:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Worksheets(ListBox1.Value).Select
End Sub

Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim msg As String

    On Error GoTo Exit
    Do
        n = n + 1
        ListBox1.AddItem Sheets(n).Name
    Loop Until n = Worksheets.Count

    If ListBox1.Value.Selected Then
        CommandButton1_Click = True
    Else
        CommandButton1_Click = False
    End If
    Exit:

End Sub
```

Comment: Put the Worksheets(ListBox1.Value).Select in the ListBox1_Click() event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you need is ListBox `Click` event handler:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    With Me.ListBox1
        If .ListIndex <> -1 Then Worksheets(.Value).Select
    End With
End Sub



Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim n As Integer

    Do
        n = n + 1
        ListBox1.AddItem Sheets(n).Name
    Loop Until n = Worksheets.Count

End Sub
```

BTW you `UserForm_Initialize()` can be a little simplified as follows

```
Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    For Each sht In Worksheets
        ListBox1.AddItem sht.Name
    Next
End Sub
```